# Combine results from multiple select statement resultsets to single record table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a very particular problem.

I need to retrieve EmployeeID, UserID, a Sum of TotalValue and SUM of COUNT of StartDate columns as a single record from my stored procedure.

Scenario :

If I try this :

```
Select EmployeeID, UserID, Sum(TotalValue), Sum(Count(StartDate))
From Employees
Group By EmployeeID, UserID
```

The problem is that I cannot Sum and Count at the same time as it gives me the following error :

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery
```

So what I did was this :

```
Select EmployeeID, UserID, TotalSummedValue, SUM(NoOfDates) FROM
(
 Select EmployeeID, UserID, SUM(TotalValue) AS TotalSummedValue, COUNT(StartDate)
 FROM Employees
 GROUP BY EmployeeID, UserID
) AS inner
GROUP BY EmployeeID, UserID
```

But now the problem is that the value returned by COUNT(StartDate) is affected by the Grouping in the inner query. 
So I essentially have to retrieve the Count and the rest of the data separately.

So I made a base query (this is a simplified version of the actual query), results of which I insert in a temporary table and reuse ->

```
Insert Into #TempBase
SELECT EmployeeID, UserID, TotalValue, StartDate FROM Employees
```

And use it like this :

```
Insert INTO #Temp2
Select EmployeeID, UserID, SUM(TotalValue) AS TotalSummedValue FROM #TempBase

Insert INTO #Temp3
Select SUM(NoOfDates) FROM
(
 Select COUNT(StartDate) AS NoOfDates FROM
 #TempBase
)
```

And then to get the whole thing out in a single record, I am currently doing this ugly thing :

```
Insert INTO #Temp4 (EmployeeID, UserID, TotalSummedValue, TotalDays)
Values((Select EmployeeID FROM #Temp2), (Select UserID FROM #Temp2),
(Select TotalSummedValue FROM #Temp2),(Select NoOfDates FROM #Temp3))

Select * from #Temp4
```

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

UPDATE : 
 (Column names are different from the example detailed above)

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRrmD.png)

[Expected Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrtVJ.png)

[Result set includes - 
1) EmployeeID, UserID, totalOrderValue for the day
2) the total no of distinct days on which orders were made]

I found the problem in my query, I was using this query, which was skewing the Count result -

```
Select EmployeeID , UserID, SUM(NoOfDays) AS TotalDays,SUM(SummedOrderValue) AS TotalOrderValue 
    FROM 
    (
     Select  EmployeeID, UserID,COUNT(DISTINCT OrderDate) AS NoOfDays,
     SUM(OrderValue) AS SummedOrderValue FROM BusinessEntity 
     GROUP BY OrderDate, EmployeeID, UserID, OrderValue
    ) AS o
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, UserID
```

But I realized, I did not really need to have OrderValue in the inner Group By clause. Removing the same gave me the proper result set -

```
Select EmployeeID , UserID, SUM(NoOfDays) AS TotalDays,SUM(SummedOrderValue) AS TotalOrderValue 
FROM 
(
 Select  EmployeeID, UserID,COUNT(DISTINCT OrderDate) AS NoOfDays,
 SUM(OrderValue) AS SummedOrderValue FROM BusinessEntity 
 GROUP BY OrderDate, EmployeeID, UserID
) AS o
GROUP BY EmployeeID, UserID
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: What is the extra value of SUMming the COUNT, as there is no grouping at all? What version of `SQL Server` are you using? Can you use `Window functions`?